# Poetry install fails with EnvCommandError

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, macos-big-sur, python-poetry

I am using macOS BigSur 11.1, poetry 1.1.4 and python 3.8.6.
In my poetry project I try to run `poetry add pillow`, but it results in `EnvCommandError`.

```
The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

Pillow is located here:

```
Pillow in /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages (8.1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by running `brew install libjpeg` .